# Guest user(with Microsoft account) added to a Team is unable to do a /teams/{id}/channels call using MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have added a MS account to a Team(Office 365 Group/Team) as Guest. The user can login to teams(With his MS Account) and see all channels in Teams client.

When doing the [channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) calls using Graph Api for the same user it fails

```
GET /teams/{id}/channels
```

For a regular group member the call works fine for Guest(with MS account) I get the following error

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "User Login. Teams is disabled for your tenant.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "e0e84ec9-ea10-47eb-9b7b-bd7099c5ace3",
      "date": "2019-07-01T10:33:15"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I enable Teams for MS Live user tenant, is there some setting or this is a bug with the current implementation of Teams Api?

Comment: If you are trything this in code, could you please pass tenantId in your login request? Please check [Teams apps and authentication with guest users and Microsoft Teams free](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/troubleshoot/faq#teams-apps-and-authentication-with-guest-users-and-microsoft-teams-free) docs.

Comment: We are already passing the tenant Id when authenticating. The login request looks like this https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tennatId}/oauth2/authorize?....

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT it seems this bug is still there. Has there been any progress on this issue?

Comment: any update on this @Wajeed-MSFT